# Ansible & Jinja2: Convert two lists into key, value dict

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I would like to combine two lists into a key, value dictionary in Ansible.

I have the following lists (AWS resource IDs):

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "vpc_natgw_ids": [
        [
            "vpc-123",
            "vpc-234",
            "vpc-345",
            "vpc-456"
        ],
        [
            "nat-098",
            "nat-987",
            "nat-876",
            "nat-765"
        ]
    ]
}
```

The first item in the first list corresponds to the first item in the second list, the second item to the other second item and so on.

I'd like to combine the two lists to get a dict like so:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "vpc_natgw_ids_dict": [
        "vpc-123": "nat-098",
        "vpc-234": "nat-987",
        "vpc-345": "nat-876",
        "vpc-456": "nat-765"
    ]
}
```

How would I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example this way:

```
set_fact:
  vpc_natgw_ids_dict: "{{ dict(vpc_natgw_ids[0] | zip(vpc_natgw_ids[1])) }}"
```

Comment: Thank you, techraf!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution posted by IRC user seschwar in #ansible on freenode.net works as well by utilizing Jinja2:

```
- set_fact:
    vpc_natgw_ids_dict: >-
      {%- set ns = namespace(ids={}) -%}
      {%- for i in vpc_natgw_ids[0] -%}
        {{- ns.ids.__setitem__(vpc_natgw_ids[0][loop.index0], vpc_natgw_ids[1][loop.index0]) -}}
      {%- endfor -%}
      {{- ns.ids -}}
- debug:
    var: vpc_natgw_ids_dict
```

Comment: what does `namespace` reference? example needs reference to that.